# Wrong renderText output on use of conditionalPanel (shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, observers

I am facing problems in rendering an output based on input in conditional panels. Below I have written a modified version of my code where I have removed all the extra stuff that was not relevant to the question.

The ui.R is

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel("Art and R"),

sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

        selectInput(
            "colspa", "Color space", choices = list("A" = "a", "B" = "b"), selected = 1
        ),  

        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.colspa == 'a'", selectInput(
                "colchoice", "Color choice", choices = list("ONE" = "one", "TWO" = "two", "THREE" = "three"), selected = 1
            )
        ),

        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.colspa == 'b'", selectInput(
                "colchoice", "Color choice", choices = list("FOUR" = "four", "FIVE" = "five", "SIX" = "six"), selected = 1
            )
        ),

        actionButton("btn", "Show!")
    ),

    mainPanel(
        textOutput("distPlot")
    )
)
))
```

And the server.R is

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
str2 <<- ""
str3 <<- ""
getResults1 <- observeEvent(input$btn, {
    str2 <<- (paste0(input$colspa))
})

getResults2 <- observeEvent(input$btn, {
    str3 <<- (paste0(input$colchoice))
})

calculate <- eventReactive(input$btn, {
    str1 <<- paste0(str2, str3)
    return(str1)
})

output$distPlot <- renderText({
    calculate()
})
})
```

If I run this application, I get correct results when `colspa` is "a" but as soon as I change `colspa` to "b" from selectInput, The output rendered is not what I want. Below is an example of the problem.

[image: Correct output when selectInput is A]
[image: Wrong output when selectInput is B]

Comment: rather than using a conditional panel could you just use the  `updateSelectInput()` function on the server side? I think the app is confused that you have two `selectInputs` labeled "colchoice" even if only one of them is displayed at any one time.

Comment: @JohnPaul I tried that before but it did not seem to work. Could you tell me how can I implement that in the case above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the same ID for two different outputs. The reason for failing was that "colchoice" was still bound to the first selectInput, since that had the same ID as the second. The following is a working example with `updateSelectInput`. Note that you need an additional `session` argument in the Server for that.

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Art and R"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # first select input
      selectInput(
        "colspa", "Color space", choices = list("A" = "a", "B" = "b"), selected = "a"
      ),
      # second select input 
      selectInput(
          "colchoice", "Color choice", choices = list("ONE" = "one", "TWO" = "two", "THREE" = "three"), selected = "one"
      ),

      actionButton("btn", "Show!")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      textOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # change choices of input$colchoice depending on input$colspa
  observeEvent(input$colspa, {
    if(input$colspa == "a") myChoices <- c("ONE" = "one", "TWO" = "two", "THREE" = "three")
    else myChoices <- c("FOUR" = "four", "FIVE" = "five", "SIX" = "six")

    updateSelectInput(session, "colchoice", choices = myChoices)
  })


  # display selected choices upon click of input$btn

  calculate <- eventReactive(input$btn, {
    paste0(input$colspa, input$colchoice)
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderText({
    calculate()
  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I figured it out in a similar manner but used 2 buttons. Yours is better. Thanks!